# BackgroundColor different for each element React Native Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, tabbar

Hope everyone's doing well.

I'm working with react native navigation and i'm stuck on a little thing.

I have created a Top Tab Navigator and i'd like to change the backgroundColor for each element according to the route.name in my tabBarItemStyle but i don't know how to do..

If anyone knows,Thanks !

(PS: a little screen of my options)

[ScreenOptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR3EJ.png)

Comment: Can you paste, in your post, the code which is in your screen?

Comment: <Tab.Screen
          name="Tout"
          component={General}
          options={{
            title: "Test"
          }}
        />

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'navigation' prop, try something like that:

```js
screenOptions={({navigation}) => ({
    yourColorProp: navigation.isFocused() ? 'green' : 'white',
})}
```

Comment: {navigation} is undefined :/